# How to stop an integer from resetting to its original value after each button press in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, button

I am making a program so that when the user presses any of the buttons the total_votes value increases by one. How do I make the total_votes value not reset back to 15 whenever I repress the button?

```
import tkinter as tk

total_votes = 15

root = tk.Tk()


class VoteButton:
    def __init__(self, row, column, text):
        self.row = row
        self.column = column
        self.text = text
        self.vbtn = tk.Button(root, text=self.text, command=lambda: self.voting(total_votes))

    def draw(self):
        self.vbtn.grid(row=self.row, column=self.column)

    def voting(self, tv):
        tv += 1
        print(tv)


btn = VoteButton(0, 0, "button")
btn.draw()

btn2 = VoteButton(0, 1, "button")
btn2.draw()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Note that changing argument `tv` will not change the original variable `total_votes` because it is passed by value for your case.

Comment: Can we see where you call `VoteButton.voting`? What does `print(tv)` give you?

Comment: print(tv) just gives me 16 over and over again.

Comment: `total_votes` doesn't get reset; it never gets changed. The value 15 (or whatever is in `total_votes`) gets passed to the `voting` method and held locally in `tv`, not the variable.

Comment: @joffan I suggest you clarify that `tv += 1` should be changed to `total_votes += 1` and make it an answer. Or I can :)

Comment: same applies to @acw1668

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing argument `tv` inside `voting()` does not change the global variable `total_votes` because only the value of `total_votes` is passed via the argument `tv` (passed by value) by the line `self.voting(total_votes)`.

To change the global variable `total_votes`, you need to update it directly inside `voting()` and declaring it as global variable inside the function via `global total_votes`:

```py
class VoteButton:
    def __init__(self, row, column, text):
        self.row = row
        self.column = column
        self.text = text
        self.vbtn = tk.Button(root, text=self.text, command=self.voting)

    ...

    def voting(self):
        global total_votes
        total_votes += 1
        print(total_votes)
```

However I would suggest to change `total_votes` to class variable of `VoteButton` to avoid using global variable:

```py
class VoteButton:
    total_votes = 15   # class variable

    def __init__(self, row, column, text):
        self.row = row
        self.column = column
        self.text = text
        self.vbtn = tk.Button(root, text=self.text, command=self.voting)

    ...

    def voting(self):
        VoteButton.total_votes += 1
        print(VoteButton.total_votes)
```

Answer (score 1):

`total_votes` isn't redefined to be `tv` in the voting function. You can fix your problem by changing the voting function, like this:

```
def voting(self, tv):
    tv += 1
    total_votes = tv
    print(tv)
```

Comment: Your solution has the same result as OP because `total_votes` inside `voting()` is a local variable, not the global one.

Comment: We can re-define total_votes so that it is a self variable.

Comment: That (a self variable) would give you a different counter per button